# Send Jar files via Netty.io

Tags: java, netty

I have written a Netty.io system in which I can easily send text files back and forth, but now I do not only want to send text files at the byte level, but if I announce before that comes a jar, even send a jar file at byte level.

Now I have tried only to send them like a normal file where logically a corrupt jar comes out.

So I send the text files:

```
    public void sendFile(Channel channel, File files, String path)  {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    sendFileInfo(channel,files,path);
                    while (file.containsKey(files.getName())) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    try {
                        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(files);
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[512];
                        int i =0;
                        int length;
                        while((length =fis.read(bytes))>0){
                            PacketOutFile512Bytes bit = new PacketOutFile512Bytes(i,files.getName(),length,bytes);
                            channel.writeAndFlush(bit);
                            if(!cache.containsKey(files.getName()))
                                cache.put(files.getName(),new HashMap<>());
                            HashMap<Integer, Timer> timecache = cache.get(files.getName());
                            timecache.put(i,new Timer());
                            timecache.get(i++).schedule(new TimerTask() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    channel.writeAndFlush(bit);
                                }
                            },Main.getInstance().getTimeout()*1000,Main.getInstance().getTimeout()*1000);
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        }
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
}


public void writeFile(Channel channel, String file, int length){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                File sending = new File(path.get(file),file);
                try {
                    sending.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    for(int i =0; i< amountofPackets.get(file);i++)
                        fos.write(cache.get(file).get(i),0,length);
                    fos.close();
                    channel.writeAndFlush(new PacketOutFileSucess(file));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Now I am looking for a method how to copy a jar on level of bytes that I can send with the same package.

This is how the packet looks for the byte snippet:

```
import de.letsplaybar.fileserver.ValueSizeException;
import lombok.Getter;

public class PacketInFile512Bytes implements Packet {

    private @Getter int packetId;

    private @Getter String name;

    private @Getter int length;

    private @Getter byte[] value;


    public PacketInFile512Bytes() {
        value = new byte[512];
    }

    public PacketInFile512Bytes(int packetId, String name, int length, byte[] value) throws ValueSizeException {
        if(value.length != 512)
            throw new ValueSizeException();
        this.packetId = packetId;
        this.name = name;
        this.length = length;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public void read(PacketSerilizer serilizer) {
        packetId = serilizer.readInt();
        name = serilizer.readString();
        length = serilizer.readInt();
        for (int i = 0; i<512;i++)
            value[i] = serilizer.readByte();
    }

    @Override
    public void write(PacketSerilizer serilizer) {
        serilizer.writeInt(packetId);
        serilizer.writeString(name);
        serilizer.writeInt(length);
        serilizer.writeBytes(value);
    }
}
```

Who knows a way how I can do that?

Ever thank you in advance.

Letsplaybar